# PDF and image are different by using puppeteer in Python

Tags: python-3.x, puppeteer

I cannot understand why exported PDF has black line on the right side which is not visible in browser and exported image.

Any suggestions ??

Python version 3.6.3 
Puppeteer version 1.9.0

[image]

[image: PDF]

EDIT
link to PDF
http://www.filedropper.com/table_4

Comment: Ready :) http://www.filedropper.com/table_4

Comment: @Wojciech533 Isn't puppeteer a node.js library? How do you use it in python? (genuinely curious)

Comment: I am using pyppeteer in python